# Android to iphone and vice versa emoji smiley not working

Tags: android, iphone, keyboard, emoji

I developed one application in that i using emoji smiley , it working nice in all android devices.

I used following example for creating emoji smiley :

https://github.com/Hall/androidemojimap

These emoji successful encode and decode during send and receive from the server/api.

But Problem arise when my application open in iPhone ( developed for iPhone by other developer ) it display just encoded code. and vice versa for same application from iPhone to android for emoji.

So , Any one give me way to how to solve it ?

So my question is that , How to encode and decode same way in android to iPhone or iPhone to android emoji smiley ?

Please help me for right way...

Answer (score 1):

We have created Particular Mapping class to map Particular smiley with Code.

Then we send code to server and at receiver side we get emoji from Mapping class using Received emoji code.

So According to Emoji code we have Mapping all emoji.

in Android I have following code:

```
public final class SmileyMapper {

    private static final HashMap<String, String> MessageToSmiley = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        MessageToSmiley.put("<#m1>", "");
        MessageToSmiley.put("<#m2>", "");
        MessageToSmiley.put("<#m3>", "");
    }

    private static final HashMap<String, String> SmileyToMessage = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        SmileyToMessage.put("", "<#m1>");
        SmileyToMessage.put("", "<#m2>");
        SmileyToMessage.put("", "<#m3>");
    }

    /**
     * Convert Message code into Smiley chat message
     *
     * @param text input string
     * @return Smiley message
     */
    public static String replaceMessageWithSmileys(String text) {
        for (Entry<String, String> smiley : MessageToSmiley.entrySet()) {
            text = text.replaceAll(smiley.getKey(), smiley.getValue());
        }
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Smiley message into Chat Message code
     *
     * @param text input string
     * @return Smiley message code
     */
    public static String replaceSmileysWithMessage(String text) {
        for (Entry<String, String> smiley : SmileyToMessage.entrySet()) {
            text = text.replaceAll(smiley.getKey(), smiley.getValue());
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: library that i used in android , that have so many smiley like more than 70 so for all smiley do this one ?

Comment: Yes you have to map all smily. in my app i have around 800 smiley. it is tedious task though you have to do like this

Comment: so, after , library that i used that is no more useful na ?

Comment: like for baseball : MessageToSmiley.put("u26BE", "baseball"); like this one ?

Comment: Hello @Rajesh Jadav , please you can provide me your adding smiley code ? it reduce my so much time and i also thankful for that..

Comment: Use this: http://pastebin.com/B2dgHQNT. if it is helpful then pls upvote and accpet answer

Comment: it all smiley need to be add in custom keyboard ? or direct use this function while use smiley ?

Comment: you can add only you want to show in keyboard . you can remove other smiley

Comment: currently it all display as question mark or rectangular shape so how i know which smiley for perticular ?

Comment: then you have add smiley icon to drawable folder then try SmileyToMessage.put(R.drawable.smiley1, "<#m1>"); like this

Comment: So , i need to all these smiley images or any place to i got this all these smiley images ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87858/discussion-between-joseph-mekwan-and-rajesh-jadav).